# deploying camping web app on windows server 2008 as a service

Tags: ruby, windows-server-2008, thin, camping

I have a question about running a camping web app as a windows server 2008 service.
So far we've done as described in this post: http://www.dixis.com/?p=140 including the step for windows server 2008. However, the service starts and runs, but the app is not triggered.

We're using the rack config file like so:

```
 $LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path('..') 
 require './review' 
 rack_log = File.new("rack_log_file.txt", "a+") 
 use Rack::CommonLogger, rack_log 
 Review.create 
 run Review
```

The app runs fine if we start it in command line with the command "`thin start`".

Registry key settings:

```
Application=c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe
AppDirectory=c:\camping\review
AppParameters=c:\camping\review\thin start -p 3301
```

Can anyone help on this issue?

Regards,
seba

Comment: Do you have any logs? I don't know a lot about Windows Server 2008 services so without an error log it's a bit difficult to help.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any error logs. If we run from command line like I said above everything works, rack log records normally and the app behaves as expected. But this is not a possible scenario and we need it run as a service. When we run it as a service the only message is that Review service has been successfully started. But the page is not accessible.
I have updated the post above with actual registry key settings.

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution.
The parameters value must be:

```
AppParameters=c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\thin start -p 3301
```

Camping app now runs as windows server 2008 service:)

regards,
seba